# Symfony3: Construct FormType

Tags: php, symfony

I have a form in Symfony3, which I initialize - following the docs - as followed:

```
$form=$this->createForm(BookingType::class,$booking);
```

$booking is an already existing entity, which I want to modify - but I want to modify the form depending on the entity - like:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder,$options) {
    $builder->add('name');
    if(!$this->booking->getLocation()) {
        $builder->add('location');
    }
}
```

Prior Symfony 2.8 it was possible to construct the FormType like:

```
$form=$this->createForm(new BookingType($booking),$booking);
```

Which is exactly what I want :) But in Symfony3 this method throws an exception.
How can I pass an entity to my formtype?

Comment: You can use form events for this: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/form/form_events.html

Comment: In your formType I think you can do `$entity = $builder->getData()`

Comment: @Put12co22mer2 thats it - works fine!

Comment: @cklm but if you want to change the form configuration based on the entity, you should still use the event system, so you can get strange errors.

Answer (score 6):

You can also change a form type based on custom options.

In the form type:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, $options) {
    $builder->add('name');

    if($options['localizable']) {
        $builder->add('location');
    }
}

public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'localizable' => true,
    ));
}
```

In the controller:

```
$form = $this->createForm(BookingType::class, $booking, array(
    'localizable' => !$booking->getLocation(),
));
```

Comment: Works for me, thanks you so much, I did not remember how to change the default options!